# Docker UCP setting up loadbalancer problems :(

Tags: load-balancing, docker

I'm having trouble configuring the proxy on my test docker UCP setup.
I've got a 3 node test setup and only a single controller (so no HA)

I downloaded the UCP client bundle inside my controller node (192.168.123.14, boot2docker) and put the ca.pem, cert.pem and key.pem inside /etc/docker/ssl/
After that I ran the following command:

```
docker exec -ti ucp-kv curl --cacert /etc/docker/ssl/ca.pem --cert /etc/docker/ssl/cert.pem --key /etc/docker/ssl/key.pem https://192.168.123.14:12379/v2/keys/interlock/v1/config -XPUT -d \
value='listenAddr=":8080"
dockerURL="tcp://192.168.123.14:2376"
tlsCaCert="/certs/ca.pem"
tlsCert="/certs/cert.pem"
tlsKey="/certs/key.pem"
[[Extensions]]
Name="nginx"
ConfigPath="/etc/conf/nginx.conf"
PidPath="/etc/conf/nginx.pid"
BackendOverrideAddress=""
ConnectTimeout=5000
ServerTimeout=10000
ClientTimeout=10000
MaxConn=1024
Port=80
SyslogAddr=""
NginxPlusEnabled=false
AdminUser="admin"
AdminPass=""
SSLCertPath=""
SSLCert=""
SSLPort=443
SSLOpts=""
User="www-data"
WorkerProcesses=2
RLimitNoFile=65535
ProxyConnectTimeout=600
ProxySendTimeout=600
ProxyReadTimeout=600
SendTimeout=600
SSLCiphers=
"HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5"
SSLProtocols="SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"'
```

After I ran that command I get a jsonlike key-value pair string, so I guess it worked ?
/certs/ca.pem etc is empty though...
I don't remember setting up certificates and keys for any of my docker nodes (so maybe that's the problem?)

Then, I go to the node where my load balancer will be running (192.168.123.39, boot2docker). This node is also part of the UCP cluster.
I pulled the git interlock-lbs repo

I set the CONTROLLER_IP=19.168.123.14 and did a docker-compose up -d inside (interlock-lbs/interlock-nginx).
But when I check the docker-compose logs I get the following errors:

```
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:32:33 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:32:34 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:32:35 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:32:36 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:32:38 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
interlock_1 | time="2016-04-19T12:32:31Z" level=info msg="interlock 1.0.0 (49863fc)"
interlock_1 | time="2016-04-19T12:32:31Z" level=debug msg="using kv: addr=etcd://192.168.123.14:12379"
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
interlock_1 | time="2016-04-19T12:32:31Z" level=debug msg="Trusting certs with subjects: [0\x1e1\x1c0\x1a\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x13UCP Cluster Root CA]"
interlock_1 | time="2016-04-19T12:32:31Z" level=debug msg="configuring TLS for KV"
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:32:40 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
interlock_1 | time="2016-04-19T12:32:31Z" level=fatal msg="Near line 31 (last key parsed 'Extensions.SSLCiphers'): Expected value but found '\n' instead."
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:32:44 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
interlock_1 | time="2016-04-19T12:32:32Z" level=info msg="interlock 1.0.0 (49863fc)"
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:32:50 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
interlock_1 | time="2016-04-19T12:32:32Z" level=debug msg="using kv: addr=etcd://192.168.123.14:12379"
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:33:04 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
interlock_1 | time="2016-04-19T12:32:32Z" level=debug msg="Trusting certs with subjects: [0\x1e1\x1c0\x1a\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x13UCP Cluster Root CA]"
nginx_1 | 2016/04/19 12:33:30 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?
My source is: https://www.docker.com/sites/default/files/RA_UCP%20Load%20Balancing-Feb%202016_1.pdf page 11 (3A Interlock and NGINX)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, you don't need to have the client bundle on the controller node to execute the `docker exec` command.  The `--cacert /etc/docker/ssl/ca.pem --cert /etc/docker/ssl/cert.pem --key /etc/docker/ssl/key.pem` options refer to the certs that are inside the `ucp-kv` container.

As for the nginx issue, I'm running into the same thing.  I will come back if I find a solution!